# get WPF Window Context to Form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I made a new Project for an Update form and used WinForms for it (my main Project is using WPF).

So I've made some Properties in MainWindow. One of them is:

```
public Form Context
{
   get { return this; }
}
```

This is fine when MainWindow is a WinForm. But it isn't it is a WPF Window.
So this is not working because of an Error.

```
The type MainWindow can not be converted in System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

Is there a way to solve this?

What I tried is to use WindowsFormsHost. So i add WindowsFormsHost to my MainWindow:

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <wf:Form x:Name="form" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

And edited the MainWindow.xaml.cs as follows:

```
public Form Context
{
   get { return form; }
}
```

But i got an XamlParseException.

Comment: Your MainWindow is a `System.Windows.Window` but your property 'Context' is of type `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. They are completely different types, what are you trying to do?

Comment: It sounds like you want to host a Windows Forms control in a WPF app. Try and follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-windows-forms-control-in-wpf-by-using-xaml

Comment: @mnistic yea nice. What I need for Context ? The Walkthough is for MaskedTextBox ^^

Comment: @Luranis Not sure what you mean? If you need more help you will have to provide more code to help understand what you're doing.

Comment: I want to open a WinForms Dialog in my MainWindow. Thats why Form Context should get "this". But then i get the error. So i need to fill "this". I open the WinForms as follows in another Project:
`if (new SharpUpdateAcceptForm(this.applicationInfo, update)
                            .ShowDialog(this.applicationInfo.Context) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        this.DownloadUpdate(update);`

Comment: You will most likely have to use WindowInteropHelper: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms618134.aspx

Comment: @mnistic I edited my topic to give you more to understand.

Answer (score 1):

WinForms and WPF are different frameworks, both stepping on the Win32 API. In this sence, the only common thing between the objects Form and Window, would be the HWND, i.e. the handle to the window.
In theory, if both windows know each others HWND, they can communicate via their message queues - Send(Post)Message(...), which is probably not what you are looking for.
The best approach is to stick with one of the frameworks or convert your Form to a control and host it inside WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: How you mean converting my form into a control? How can i give the window (this) to my form? If my MainWindow would be a WinForm, `get { return this; }` would be fine. But it is a WPF window and I need the same (this). I edited my question so you can see, what I tried.

Comment: In WPF, the Window class has a property Content. In XAML you define the content inside <Window> ... </Window> tag. You can convert a WPF window to a control by creating a UserControl with the window's content, for example. I haven't used WinForms in my practice, but you should be able to do the same thing. What is the anologue to a UserControl in WinFoms? A Frame?

Comment: There is no Frame in WinForms. The analogue for a Frame is a Panel. That's the thing. I need to return the Content property from WPF to WinForm.